# UIViewController "mysteriously" resets to origin=0,0 when answering an incoming call

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` in my app that rests to its original position when I'm answering an incoming call.

1. How do I set a breakpoint to catch when this happens?
2. Any idea what might be causing this?

I tried disabling autoresize and auto rotate but nothing seem to make a difference.

Comment: I think the problem is in auto layout. Wanna catch that moment? Override -(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews or -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews  and set breakpoint/ print log there

Comment: Well, a view controller doesn't have a position, rather the view it controls does.  I point that out not to be nitpicky, but because if it's a functional misunderstanding your debugging efforts might have been in the wrong place.  You can do things like override -setFrame or other methods that your view inherits and set breakpoints there to see what the call stack is showing.  It could something happening with the auto-layout system.  At the worst, I believe your app resigns active when the call comes in and you could trap there.